# Different Color For Two Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, colors

I have two monitors on one PC (extend option). The colour for two monitors are different, how can I make the colour settings.

E.g For monitor A, the colour is as shown in the below image

[image]

and for the monitor B, the colour is as shown in the below image

[image]

Comment: Soooo, what's your question exactly?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko My question is how to make the colour unique to two monitors? I would like to have the same colour of monitor A in monitor B?

Comment: Calibrate your monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that now you've posted these 2 pictures to the same web page... they now look identical? [They are identical, pretty much to the digit]

Most consumer-level monitors [& especially laptop screens] are shipped with monitor calibration that looks attractive on display in the shop, but the first thing you have to do when you get home is to change it from *attractive* to *accurate*.
To do this properly, you need a device called a colorimeter. These vary in price from entry-level at maybe $£€ 80 up to several hundreds.
Without one, you will never know when your pictures are right.

Very briefly - you connect it to USB, hang it over the screen, blocking it from other interfering light sources, & run the software. It will tell you exactly what to do. It will then generate a profile [LUT - Look Up Table] for your screen & tell your computer to apply it.

You can now see what colour things are supposed to be.

There's an in-depth tutorial at [B&H - How To Calibrate Your Monitor](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-and-solutions/how-calibrate-your-monitor) which includes links to some specific colorimeters.

There is an additional complication that sometimes arises on consumer-level graphics cards, especially apparently on Windows.
The OS & graphics card must be able to simultaneously support 2 LUTs. I don't know how to test for this on Windows with dual external displays.